# Custom IAM instance profile for elastic beanstalk instances fails on S3_MALFORMED_POLICY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've create a new iam role that i would like my instance to run as so that I can give it specific permissions to other resources my instance will need (eg parameter store, it's database instance, etc).

The default role `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` had 4 policies attached to it: AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier, AmazonSESFullAccess, AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker, AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier.

So I created a role like `my-app-role` that has the same 4 policies plus the one policy specific to this application.

However when I change the eb configuration(via console) to use this new role for it's instances, it spins for a while and ultimately displays this error with very little information:
[image]
I noticed that there is a bucket for elastic beanstalk called elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-(arn) that mentions the default elastic beanstalk role so I added another policy to `my-app-role` to grant access to that bucket as such:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-(arn)/resources/environments/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-(arn)"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However the same error occurs. There must be some permission I am still missing despite this. Does anyone know what you must do to properly create a custom eb instance role??

Comment: Hi Nick, did you use the same app name in application (Elastic Beanstalk config) and in the notebook (application.py) ?

Comment: I had also an issue at @app.route. Please check: https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/blob/master/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk/application.py

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres Hello! I dont have an application.py as this is a Django application. But the app does work with the role: `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` so I'm not really clear how the name of the app would effect the IAM role of the instance.

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344800/s3-bucket-policy-malformed-error

Comment: Yeah, the weird thing is I get that error in the EB console when I have not touched a single s3 policy. (In my q I noted that in an effort to get around that i did create one, but it had no effect on the error, and the s3 policy i created was not done by hand it was done using the policy generator so i dont think the actual policy i made is malformed, it just isnt the solution).

Comment: What if you remove `"Sid": "VisualEditor0",`

Comment: Doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the above issue and AWS support helped me out. Turns out when you first use a custom IAM instance profile with Elastic Beanstalk, it makes a call to its S3 bucket (`elasticbeanstalk-<region>-<account>`; e.g. `elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-123456789012`) and adds the new IAM role to the bucket's policy. In my case, the bucket policy was referring to a test IAM user that had long ago been deleted, but this reference to a no-longer-valid/existing user caused S3 to complain that the policy was now invalid/"malformed". Elastic Beanstalk would try for exactly 13 minutes to make its change (to the S3 bucket's policy) and would then fail with "S3_MALFORMED_POLICY" error. Removing the reference to the no-longer-existing user from the Elastic Beanstalk S3 bucket resolved the issue.